# Mentioning a user with @ using Linkify and regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm currently using the following pattern:

`Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)");`

This will find a user named `@user` for example, but it won't find `@user.` (with the trailing dot) or `@user!hello`. I'd like to basically capturing everything until the first whitespace. What pattern can I use to find these kinds of usernames?

Comment: This is confusing because your pattern already works. https://regex101.com/r/qgOTKF/1 . What isn't working?

Comment: I meant that I want to find ``user.`` and ``user.123`` for example, i.e. to include the trailing dot and chars that come after a dot but before a new whitsespace.

Comment: The pattern `@([\\S+A-Za-z0-9_]+)` you mentioned in another comment doesn't capture `@user.123`. Right? Do you want to capture really any combination not including a white-space? Also `@user1@user2` as one user?

It helps if you add a list of examples and expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@(\S+)` would capture everything up to the first whitespace.

EDIT for future reference:

`Pattern.compile("@([\\S+A-Za-z0-9_]+)");` is the actual answer if you want to capture only the `user`, the above example would have captured `user!hello`.

Comment: Ah you mean ``Pattern.compile("@([\\S+A-Za-z0-9_]+)");`` This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sorry I misread the question being to capture the `user!hello` instead of only the `user`.